# playing any video on a website (flash, divx, avi/wmv (m2ts/mts, mkv?))

Tags: video, streaming, html, embedding

How can I embed any type of video onto a webpage, youtube seems to be able to upload any type of video and I'd like to know if I can do that too without huge amounts of resources and money  (the website would be very small with definitely under 100 member, most likely under 50)

Is there a player that plays all formats, or would I have to use different players?

Also on HD videos I'd like to have a SD option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to use Divx webplayer, as it does avi, divx, and mkv (mts can convert to mkv easily)

Answer (score 4):

- [shwup.com](http://www.shwup.com/) can host collaborative video albums to share amongst friends / family / classrooms only. unlimited uploads. since you want private sharing.
- another cool way is to use one of the video APIs to upload/encode to the cloud, e.g.: [YouTube Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api), [Vimeo API](http://www.vimeo.com/api), [Hey!Watch](http://wiki.heywatch.com/API_Documentation), [Orb](https://developer.orb.com/wiki/Documentation), [Phanfare](http://help.phanfare.com/index.php/API)
- For players: [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) is pretty nice.
- [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org) is great as well.
- if you have [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) on your host, that can easily handle conversion between most popular formats
- if you're doing tons of encoding and self-hosting the files, another option is [uEncode.com](http://www.uencode.com) - an on-demand web service to convert between formats
- also you could just upload the files to a regular account on one of the sharing sites like youtube, veoh, and embed them in your site. let them provide the bandwidth :)

Comment: JW Player hands off the playing of the video to the Flash plugin, which has limited codec/container support.

Comment: you can encode it using ffmpeg or uEncode before streaming it, if the format isn't natively supported

Comment: I'd prefer the videos to visible to only members of the site (family), then people who upload can choose to link from youtube and such

Comment: shwup.com would be a pretty good app for that. no need to host a lot of stuff on a shared web host

Answer (score 2):

There is no player that plays all formats. You would either have to restrict the containers and codecs usable, or farm off reencoding to another process.

Comment: I had guessed that be the case,it seems to obvious to exist.

Answer (score 1):

I use JW Player: http://www.jeroenwijering.com/?item=JW_FLV_Player

Answer (score 1):

YouTube uses `ffmpeg` (free and open-source) to convert uploaded video to a Flash format for embedding. You can do the same, if you like.

Comment: I have heard this takes a lot of resources (is that the right word?) and that hosts dont like it.

Comment: Yes, it takes a substantial amount of resources if you're doing a lot of video processing. Issues with hosts can be resolved by getting a dedicated VPS slice somewhere like Slicehost.com or Linode.com.